# Controlling brightness in pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot the electron's probability (in an hydrogen atom), using python and matplotlib's pcolormesh.
All is well except that since the distribution drops so rapidly - some details are not visible, e.g., the surroundings of the zeroes of the radial function (in the higher energy states) are too fade, making it hard to notice that the wave function actually vanishes at some radii.

I know I can handle this with some rescaling and "adjustments" to the wave function, but I would rather tweak my plotting skills and realize how to do this with matplotlib.

I want to adjust the heat map so that more of the map would be bright.
Is there a way to control its sensitivity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about the `norm`, `vmin` and `vmax` keyword arguments to `pcolormesh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) do to that. I've used it in quite similar situations with very good results.

One way to do that:

```
normalized = original/original.max()  # rescale to between 0 and 1
corrected = numpy.power(normalized, gamma) # try values between 0.5 and 2 as a start point
plt.imshow(corrected)
```

This works because elevating the interval between 0 and 1 to a given exponent yields monotonically increasing results that cross 0,0 and 1,1. This is similar to moving the middle slider of Photoshop/GIMP "levels" dialog.

EDIT: better yet, it seems that Matplotlib already has [a class for that](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.PowerNorm).